# How to download raw data from google spread sheet in python

Tags: python

I am want the data that is shown in the google spread sheet, but there is no download option available. I tried using the Beautifulsoup4 library but was not able to figure it out.

this is the data:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please post your current code or detailed steps of how you've tried to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beautiful soup method you tried using will work like this way.

```
read_url =  urllib.request.urlopen('your_sheet_url').read() #read the url
data = BeautifulSoup(read_url,"html.parser")
table = data.table                                          #extract table 

output_rows = []
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['State','','Confirmed','Recovered','Deaths','Active','Last_Updated_Time'])
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):                      #iterate though rows
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:                                 #iterate though columns
        print(column.text)
        output_row.append(column.text)                     #append into a list
    print(len(output_row))
    output_rows.append(output_row)
    try:
        df = df.append(pd.Series(output_row,index = df.columns.tolist()),ignore_index = True) #add to the final dataframe
    except:
        pass
df.toexcel("Output.xlsx")                              # save the datafram as excel file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `google-api-python-client`.

There's a Quickstart document available [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

It boils down to something like this:

```
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '<your spreadsheet id>'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = '<your desired range>'
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

But make sure to read the full Quickstart to get the full picture. (The sample code is taken from there.)